# R digest::digest() does not return expected hashes

Tags: r, hash

I am trying out R's digest package. I am using multiple functions (digest(..., algo = ...), sha1(), sha1_digest()) but none of them return the same hash values that I check via online hash generators. The hash generators are consistent "among themselves", so I think I am not doing something properly, but I am unsure.

For instance:
My R (and https://rdrr.io/rforge/digest/) return this:

```
> digest::digest("aaa", algo =  "crc32")
[1] "acdd051e"
```

whereas
https://crc32.online/ gives for the same

```
"aaa"
f007732d
```

The discrepancies persist with sha1 and md5.
I tried to google the issue but no relevant hits are displayed for "R digest does not match"...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `serialize=FALSE` in the arguments to `digest()`, or it will serialize the input (to convert arbitrary objects to ascii) before processing.  That changes the input string.  With `serialize = FALSE`, you get the same as the reference method:

```r
digest::digest("aaa", algo =  "crc32", serialize = FALSE)
#> [1] "f007732d"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>